# How to resolve C# web api error 404 not found

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api-routing, webapi

I have created a C# Web API and I am able to access it on local host but post server deployment I am receiving 404 not found error.
Postman shows error - 'The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.'.

I have published the code using visual studio and then uploaded the files using file-zilla to the server.
The folder on the server is marked as an application.
I am able to access a sample html file present in the folder but not the api itself.

The Global.asax.cs has below code -

```
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true;
    }
}
```

RouteConfig.cs

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }

        );
}
```

WebApiConfig.cs

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    // Web API configuration and services

    // Web API routes
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
    config.Filters.Add(new BasicAuthenticationAttribute());
}
```

I am trying to invoke the normal get method

```
[BasicAuthentication]
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/getmethodapi")]
public IEnumerable<string> Get()
{
    return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
}
```

The URI i am accessing is something like -

```
https://mysampleapp.com/sampleFolder/api/getmethodapi
```

I am able to get the values using Postman as well as with C# console application on local host.
Any help/suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: why you have sampleFolder in URL?could you please show entire controller

Comment: Is sampleFolder your RoutePrefix?

Comment: @Dmytro Shabanov &  @Shahid Manzoor Bhat 
We have different folders on the server and the web api mentioned here is deployed in the SampleFolder.
```

Comment: Route prefix is "api/getmethodapi"

Comment: Please use this url https://mysampleapp.com/api/getmethodapi you dont have to pass the deployed folder name in the URL.You can read more about it here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api

Comment: I have tried that but still the 404 error

Comment: @Pri645 When you pull up https://mysampleapp.com/  in browser do you see your API home page?

Comment: Did you configure the application in IIS?

Comment: The service is created in 4.5 .net version and the app pool at my server supports lower versions than this. Could that cause this issue